# Isn't a fast-forward merge the same as a hard reset?

Tags: git

It seems like doing:

```
git merge --ff-only mybranch
```

(if it succeeds) is the same as:

```
git reset --hard mybranch
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 4):

Correct but with one additional requirement: they act the same if the `git merge --ff-only` would succeed **and** you have no uncommitted changes sitting in your work-tree.

(If you have uncommitted changes, `git merge --ff-only` can still succeed if those uncommitted changes are to files not affected by the fast-forward operation.  In this particular case, git leaves the uncommitted changes uncommitted.  If you use the `git reset --hard` method, you wipe out your uncommitted changes.  Note: I haven't tried `git merge --ff-only` with uncommitted-but-not-conflicting changes, but I would expect that to succeed as well.)